# There are $n\geq2$ people, probability $p$ that two men are friends, independently to the others pairs.

Tags: probability

There are $n\geq2$ people, probability $p$ that two men are friends, independently to the others pairs.

Denote $X_{n,p}$:= The numbers of the men without friends.

(a) Find $E[X_{n,p}]$

**My solution:**

I think the correct answer is $E[X_{n,p}]=$$2 \choose n$ $(1-p)$, but I am really not sure.

Any way I try to solve it using indicators, and I get stuck

Denote $$X_{i,j}=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{i,j not friends}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

$E[X_{n,p}]=E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}X_{i,j}]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}E[X_{i,j}]=$

I don't know how to solve it.

I'll be grateful for help, thanks!

Comment: It is more usual to write ${n \choose 2}$ rather than ${2 \choose n}$ for $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  Here ${n \choose 2} (1-p)$ is the expected number of non-friend pairs rather than individuals without any friends

Comment: I would start by calculating the probability a particular individual has no friends

Comment: For small $n$ it's easy enough to list all possibilities, giving $E[X_{2,p}] = 2(1-p)$ and $E[X_{3,p}] = 3(1-p)^2$. The general solution should match those.